# Generic Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, angular-material

I am trying to create generic dialog component (based on @angular/material), that will be mounted by the router.

Example, how MaterialDialog works without generics

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { ConcreteComponent } from '../concrete/concrete.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapping-component',
  template: '<div></div>',
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class WrappingComponent implements OnInit {
  private ref: MdDialogRef<ConcreteComponent>;

  constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ref = this.dialog.open(ConcreateComponent, {});
  }
}
```

If I apply TS generics mechanically, I get compilation error in ngOnInit.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-router-modal',
  templateUrl: './router-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./router-modal.component.css']
})
export class RouterModalComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  private ref: MdDialogRef<T>;

  constructor(
    private dialog: MdDialog,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ref = this.dialog.open<T>(T); //'T' only refers to to a type, but was used as a value here.
  }
}
```

Ideas? How to make this work?

Comment: Who did downvote me and why? :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, where people downvote things they don't understand. 

PS: I don't quite understand what you are asking, but I definitely didn't downvote you.

Comment: Any luck on this?